# VHDL variable increment works in simulation and behaves differently post synthesis

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesis

Hello I have a state machine that reads from BRAM sends data to a compute core and then writes results back in the BRAM after that the address are incremented so that the next item in the bram can be fed to the compute core. The increment is happening erratically in the state machine. I simulated the code(after stripping down unnecessary stuff) and the increment looks fine in simulation. Can some one please help me to figure out whats wrong. Thanks a bunch for all the help

```
    --The bulk of my glue logic to bring it all together. 
process(Bus2IP_Clk,ap_rst,ap_done)
variable in_a_addrb : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
variable in_b_addrb : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
variable out_r_addrb : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
begin
if(ap_rst = '1' ) then 
gcd_cs <= wait_for_reset;
in_a_addrb := "0000000000";
in_b_addrb := "0000110010";
out_r_addrb := "0001101110";
elsif (Bus2IP_Clk'event and Bus2IP_Clk = '1') then
gcd_cs <= gcd_ns;
end if;
case gcd_cs is 

when wait_for_reset =>
intrpt <= '0';
slv_reg6(0) <= '0';
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
if(ap_rst = '0')then 
gcd_ns <= wait_for_bram_ready;
else
gcd_ns <= wait_for_reset;

end if;
when wait_for_bram_ready =>
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000000010";
if(bram_ready = '1')then
web <= "0";
gcd_ns <= load_input_a;
else
gcd_ns <= wait_for_bram_ready;
end if;
when load_input_a =>
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
addrb <= in_a_addrb;
in_a <= doutb;
gcd_ns <= load_input_b;
when load_input_b =>
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000000100";
addrb <= in_b_addrb;
in_b <= doutb;
gcd_ns <= start_compute;
when start_compute => 
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000000101";
ap_start <= '1';
gcd_ns <= wait_for_done;
when wait_for_done => 
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000000110";
if(ap_done = '1')then
ap_start <= '0';
web <= "1";
addrb <= out_r_addrb;
dinb <= output;
gcd_ns <= increment_addresses_1;
else
gcd_ns <= wait_for_done;
end if;
when increment_addresses_1 => 
web <= "0";
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000000111";
gcd_ns <= increment_addresses;
when increment_addresses => 
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000001000";
if(in_a_addrb = "0000000111") then
gcd_ns <= stop_compute;
else
in_a_addrb := in_a_addrb +'1';
in_b_addrb := in_b_addrb +'1';
out_r_addrb := out_r_addrb + '1';
gcd_ns <= load_input_a;
end if;
when stop_compute =>
state_tracker <= "00000000000000000000000000001001";
gcd_ns <= stop_compute; 
slv_reg6(0) <= '1'; 
intrpt <= '1';

end case;
in_a_addrb_d <= in_a_addrb;
in_b_addrb_d <= in_b_addrb;
out_r_addrb_d <= out_r_addrb;
end process;
```

Comment: It WILL be erratic; this is NOT how to write either a single-process state machine OR a 2-process one. There's a bunch of code happening outside the clock edge statement. Use one of the two standard state machine forms (and I strongly recommend the 1-process form over the 2-process), get THAT working in sim before proceeding. Yesterday's accepted answer showed you how, yet you have gone back today to an incorrect form of process.

Comment: Actually this process works fine in simulation. also the steering logic is inside the clock edge and hence forces state changes only on clock edge. The only erroneous part is the increment.

Comment: I believe you when you say the current form works in simulation. However : is it translatable in its current form into reliable hardware? The standard forms are. You WILL need AT LEAST to bring the variable increments into the clocked part.

Answer (score 2):

All of your additions are done outside of the clock event. In simulation this may "work" because the process only gets simulated when a signal in the sensitivity list changes. The sensitivity list exists mostly to make simulation more computationally efficient. When you try to implement this into real hardware, items outside of the clock event will become combinational logic that "executes" constantly. This is similar to hooking the output of an inverter to itself without a register in between - it doesn't make any sense. Brian Drummond speaks truth when he says that you should convert this to a regular state machine form to avoid these kinds of errors.

State machines with this kind of architecture can work, despite being more difficult to read and use. The important part is that anything that needs to store information (such as the state) needs to be split into a current and a next, with that transition happening on the clock edge. You do this with the explicit state, but the values of the counters are also part of the machine's state data, and need to receive the same treatment. Using a standard form (with everything occurring on the clock edge) means that you don't have to duplicate all the signals/variables for your storage elements, nor figure out which signals are in fact storage elements, making everything easier.

Comment: The synthesizer should also have generated nasty warnings about the sensitivity list being wrong.  As well as half a dozen latches being requested.

Comment: Thanks i split my code into a two process state machine. i am synthesizing now, fingers crossed. Also when i synthesized my code previously i did not see any warnings i am using edk ver 14.1 for this project Although thanks for the explanation